# How to simulate iOS Background Fetch using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I have searching for sometime but couldn't find how to simulate iOS Background Fetch using Visual Studio 2015. There seems to be a way to do it in XCode but I couldn't find anything for Visual Studio 2015.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the project options and goto the `iOS Run Options`. Under the `Execution Mode`, change it from `Normal` to `Background Fetch`.

[image]

Place a breakpoint within your `PerformFetch` override and start debugging the app, it will be launched with the `mlaunch` option of `--launch-for-background-fetch`

```
./mlaunch --help
    ~~~
    --launch-for-background-fetch
         Launch due to a background fetch
    ~~~
```

Note: There are some issues that I know about

`Remote Simulator to Windows`: This does not work all(?)/most the time(?). Disable it for your background fetch debugging as your app on the remote simulator does not need screen/touch interactions as it is running in a simulated background mode.

Some VS versions produce `Error HE0042` in the error listing/log when using background fetch mode.

> error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'com.companyname.App4' on the device 'iOS 11.1 (15B87) - iPhone 8': The request to open "com.companyname.App4" failed.

Those versions are just plain broke and you will need to use VS4M to test/debug your background fetch.

If you are using a custom Xcode location you will get a failure since they do not place spaces between the options.

[image]

So, instead of using the drop-down to set `Background Fetch`, use the cmd-line option directly in the mlaunch args `_--launch-for-background-fetch_` adding a space before and after the option

Comment: Awesome anwer! it's not hitting the breakpoint but the code did get executed once, which is enough for now. For the record, I changed the drop down, I got HE0042 error. I undo it, added args and the app continued to get terminated. I then again set the dropdown (removed args) and the code executed. :/ weird

Comment: @Obi-WanSpock It can act strangely from VS(windows), now using VS4M there is the same option as I shown above and a menu item to trigger background fetch that becomes enabled in any project that has the background fetch enabled in the info.plist. Debugging BG fetch on VS4M always works...

Comment: Hey! @SushiHangover How do you use the cmd-line option directly on IOS debugging with a Windows remote machine? I seem to be getting the last issue.

Comment: @Tvt Review the `mlaunch` options (located on the the Mac at `/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin`), just execute `mlaunch` and it will spew out all the cmd line options.

Comment: ok thank you @SushiHangover! I found the location with the terminal. Will now figure out how to execute the mlaunch :)