# PerformFetch is never called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement background fetch in xamarin.ios application, inspite of enabling background fetch, It is never getting called.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
   // tried this also 
   // UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.BackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum);

   UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(60);

   // Other code
}


public override async void PerformFetch(UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{          
    Console.WriteLine("Perform fetch called..!!");
    var result = await FetchImage("https://www.xamarin.com/content/images/pages/branding/assets/xamagon.png");

    completionHandler(result);
}
```

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: On simulator and device both..

Comment: Are you actually initiating a background fetch? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407330/how-to-simulate-ios-background-fetch-using-visual-studio-2015/47410274#47410274

Comment: I have tried on device as same as you provided in link, but app is being terminated automatically after applying the same..

Answer (score 0):

Did you you request the right permissions in your info.plist?

You set your minimum background fetchinterval to 60, while its suggested not to go under 900.

I would suggest to take a look at [this xamarin blogpost about performing Background data fetches](https://blog.xamarin.com/add-background-data-refresh-to-ios-apps/). It is detailed and nicely explained.